# Issue Launching Gvim on Windows

Tags: gvim

I installed the Windows distribution of GVim and then installed Python3.9.
I now get the following error message when trying to launch GVim, and have no idea how to fix it.

[image]

I've tried changing my _gvimrc file and even renaming it, but no luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're just printing some values in your vimrc or gvimrc. Search for `echom` (or maybe just `echo`) in both.

Comment: I don't think that is it. I don't have any echo commands in my _gvimrc

Comment: Is the message that I am receiving difinetely related to my gvimrc file?

Comment: You don't have a vimrc file? On windows that usually will be named `_vimrc` and be in the same dir as your `_gvimrc`. There's no "definitely" about it coming from a [g]vimrc. It could come from any non-official code/config (e.g. plugins). All I know is that that "Message" in the title suggests an echo statement somewhere. It doesn't look like an error message since there's no mention of "Error" anywhere.

Comment: Do you have `ag` or `ack` or something like that? Search your `vimfiles` dir for "invalid_option". That's another approach you could take. (You can use `grep -r` if you don't have any of the alternatives. Or some native windows tool that does similar things....can't help you with an actual name there.)

Comment: If you're positive that it only started happening when you enabled Python then the last thing I can think of is any Python program being run on Vim startup...maybe that's doing the printing. But that's going to be very specific to your environment and I don't have much to suggest around that. BTW, that `formtprg_option` looks to have a typo in it which suggests a very human and local thing. :)